# Modify CTE to reference another field?

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I have the CTE below working well in re-cursing an employee table and building an expanded list of the employee id passed to it as well as all direct, and indirect reports.

I'm trying to make a sister CTE to use user name instead of employee id, but I get no data back after I make the changes...

Here is my working code with `employeeID`, how can I get this to work with `NTID` (employee) and `managerNTID` (manager)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetEmployeeHierarchy   
(    
  @EmployeeId int = null  
)  
RETURNS TABLE   
AS  
RETURN   
(  
  WITH yourcte AS  
  (  
    SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, NTID, FullName--, Name  
    FROM Employees  
    WHERE EmployeeId = isnull(@EmployeeId,EmployeeId)  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.ManagerID, e.NTID, e.FullName--, e.Name  
    FROM Employees e  
    JOIN yourcte y ON e.ManagerID = y.EmployeeId  
  )  
SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, NTID, FullName--, Name  
FROM yourcte  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `managerNTID` references the manager's `NTID` column - try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetEmployeeHierarchyNew(@EmployeeNTID int = null)  
RETURNS TABLE   
AS  
  RETURN   
  (  
    WITH NewCTE AS  
    (  
      SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, NTID, FullName--, Name  
      FROM Employees  
      WHERE NTID = ISNULL(@EmployeeNTID, EmployeeNTID)  

      UNION ALL  

      SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.ManagerID, e.NTID, e.FullName--, e.Name  
      FROM Employees e  
      JOIN NewCTE y ON e.ManagerNTID = y.NTID  
    )  
    SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, NTID, FullName--, Name  
    FROM NewCTE
  )
```

Comment: i fixed this line: WHERE NTID = ISNULL(@EmployeeNTID, EmployeeNTID) so that is is: WHERE NTID = ISNULL(@UserName, NTID) because the analougous relationship between employeeID and managerID is actualy NTID and managerNTID. even with this fixed i get syntax errors. ideas?

Comment: @kacalapy: syntax errors **where**?? What line, what statement??